# How do you solve: $4^{x^2-x-6} = 7$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I know for a fact that it could be solved using logarithms.
But i was stuck at a point in the middle of solving and i need help. I would be grateful if you could show how to find the value/s of x  ( logarithms method )

Comment: If you take the $\ln$ of both sides, you get $$x^2-x-6=\frac{\ln7}{\ln4}$$Can you solve from here?

Comment: You could also try taking $\log_4(\cdot)$ on both sides, which gives $$x^2-x-6=\log_{4}7$$ which you solve like a normal quadratic

Comment: Move the $\ln$ object to the left side, and group $-6$ with the term. Then, you can use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

This is the process you would use

$4^{x^2-x-6}=7 \longrightarrow  \ln(4^{x^2-x-6})=\ln{7} \longrightarrow \ln{4} (x^2-x-6) =\ln{7} \longrightarrow x^2-x-6 = \frac{\ln{7}}{\ln{4}} \longrightarrow x^2-x-(6+\frac{\ln{7}}{\ln{4}})=0$

Now you could use the quadratic equation.

$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4*(-6-\frac{\ln{7}}{\ln{4}})}}{2}$